# Implement choosing over 2 lenses in haskell

Tags: haskell, lenses

I'm practicing for my exam Haskell in 2 weeks. Now I'm making some exercises, but I'm stuck on this one.

> Implement a function `choosing` that is given 2 lenses and should return a new lens that works with `Either`-values.

I'm given this code:

```
type Lens s a = forall f . Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s

--------------------------------------------------------------
-- Lens s1 a             :: Functor f => a -> f a -> s1 -> f s1
-- Lens s2 a             :: Functor f => a -> f a -> s2 -> f s2
-- Lens (Either s1 s2) a :: Functor f => a -> f a -> (Either s1 s2) -> f (Either s1 s2)
--------------------------------------------------------------
choosing :: Lens s1 a -> Lens s2 a -> Lens (Either s1 s2) a
choosing lns1 lns2 = undefined
```

Now, I'm completely stuck. I think I should be using fmap to solve this issue, but I don't know how to combine these 2 lenses.

So, with the help of @shang and @klappvisor I found the full answer to this question:

```
choosing :: Lens s1 a -> Lens s2 a -> Lens (Either s1 s2) a
choosing lns1 lns2 = (\func x -> case x of
                                Left value  -> (\z -> Left $ set lns1 z value) <$> (func (view lns1 value))
                                Right value -> (\z -> Right $ set lns2 z value) <$> (func (view lns2 value)))
```

Comment: if you run out of luck and want to see solution follow [this link](http://lpaste.net/6450842794700308480) and read really [nice article](https://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-1) about lenses with exact your exercise in it

Comment: @klappvisor: thank you! The article is really handy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great exercise problem because you don't even have to know anything about lenses to implement the solution. You can just follow the types.

```
choosing :: Lens s1 a -> Lens s2 a -> Lens (Either s1 s2) a
choosing lns1 lns2 = undefined
```

The return type `Lens (Either s1 s2) a` is an alias for `forall f . Functor f => (a -> f a) -> Either s1 s2 -> f (Either s1 s2)` so you know that you have to return some kind of function that takes two parameters:

```
choosing lns1 lns2 = \func x -> undefined
```

The type of `func` is `(a -> f a)` and `x` is a value of type `Either s1 s2`. We can't do much with `func` yet but we know enough about `x` that we can pattern match on it:

```
choosing lns1 lns2 = \func x -> case x of
    Left l  -> undefined
    Right r -> undefined
```

Now, using `lns1`, `lns2`, `func` and the knowledge that the type `f` is a functor (so you can use `fmap`) you just need to implement the branches of the case expression so that both produce a value of type `f (Either s1 s2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a really clear explanation :)